# Reading an Excel sheet using POI's XSSF and SAX (Event API)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an Excel sheet using POI's XSSF and SAX (Event API). The Excel sheet has thousands of rows of user information like user name, email, address, age, department etc.

I need to read each row from Excel, convert it into a User object and add this User object to a List of User objects.

I can read the Excel sheet successfully, but I am not sure at what point while reading I should create an instance of the User object and populate it with the data from the Excel sheet.

Below is my entire working code.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException;
    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageAccess;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.ReadOnlySharedStringsTable;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class ExcelSheetParser {

        enum xssfDataType {
            BOOL, ERROR, FORMULA, INLINESTR, SSTINDEX, NUMBER,
        }

        int countrows = 0;

        class XSSFSheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {

            /**
             * Table with styles
             */
            private StylesTable stylesTable;

            /**
             * Table with unique strings
             */
            private ReadOnlySharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable;

            /**
             * Destination for data
             */
            private final PrintStream output;

            private List<?> list = new ArrayList();

            private Class clazz;

            /**
             * Number of columns to read starting with leftmost
             */
            private final int minColumnCount;

            // Set when V start element is seen
            private boolean vIsOpen;

            // Set when cell start element is seen;
            // used when cell close element is seen.
            private xssfDataType nextDataType;

            // Used to format numeric cell values.
            private short formatIndex;
            private String formatString;
            private final DataFormatter formatter;

            private int thisColumn = -1;
            // The last column printed to the output stream
            private int lastColumnNumber = -1;

            // Gathers characters as they are seen.
            private StringBuffer value;

            /**
             * Accepts objects needed while parsing.
             * 
             * @param styles
             *            Table of styles
             * @param strings
             *            Table of shared strings
             * @param cols
             *            Minimum number of columns to show
             * @param target
             *            Sink for output
             */
            public XSSFSheetHandler(StylesTable styles,
                    ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, int cols, PrintStream target, Class clazz) {
                this.stylesTable = styles;
                this.sharedStringsTable = strings;
                this.minColumnCount = cols;
                this.output = target;
                this.value = new StringBuffer();
                this.nextDataType = xssfDataType.NUMBER;
                this.formatter = new DataFormatter();
                this.clazz = clazz;
            }

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if ("inlineStr".equals(name) || "v".equals(name)) {
                    vIsOpen = true;
                    // Clear contents cache
                    value.setLength(0);
                }
                // c => cell
                else if ("c".equals(name)) {
                    // Get the cell reference
                    String r = attributes.getValue("r");
                    int firstDigit = -1;
                    for (int c = 0; c < r.length(); ++c) {
                        if (Character.isDigit(r.charAt(c))) {
                            firstDigit = c;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    thisColumn = nameToColumn(r.substring(0, firstDigit));

                    // Set up defaults.
                    this.nextDataType = xssfDataType.NUMBER;
                    this.formatIndex = -1;
                    this.formatString = null;
                    String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
                    String cellStyleStr = attributes.getValue("s");
                    if ("b".equals(cellType))
                        nextDataType = xssfDataType.BOOL;
                    else if ("e".equals(cellType))
                        nextDataType = xssfDataType.ERROR;
                    else if ("inlineStr".equals(cellType))
                        nextDataType = xssfDataType.INLINESTR;
                    else if ("s".equals(cellType))
                        nextDataType = xssfDataType.SSTINDEX;
                    else if ("str".equals(cellType))
                        nextDataType = xssfDataType.FORMULA;
                    else if (cellStyleStr != null) {
                        // It's a number, but almost certainly one
                        // with a special style or format
                        int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(cellStyleStr);
                        XSSFCellStyle style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
                        this.formatIndex = style.getDataFormat();
                        this.formatString = style.getDataFormatString();
                        if (this.formatString == null)
                            this.formatString = BuiltinFormats
                                    .getBuiltinFormat(this.formatIndex);
                    }
                }

            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
                    throws SAXException {

                String thisStr = null;

                // v => contents of a cell
                if ("v".equals(name)) {
                    // Process the value contents as required.
                    // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
                    switch (nextDataType) {

                    case BOOL:
                        char first = value.charAt(0);
                        thisStr = first == '0' ? "FALSE" : "TRUE";
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        thisStr = "\"ERROR:" + value.toString() + '"';
                        break;

                    case FORMULA:
                        // A formula could result in a string value,
                        // so always add double-quote characters.
                        thisStr = '"' + value.toString() + '"';
                        break;

                    case INLINESTR:
                        // TODO: have seen an example of this, so it's untested.
                        XSSFRichTextString rtsi = new XSSFRichTextString(value
                                .toString());
                        thisStr = '"' + rtsi.toString() + '"';
                        break;

                    case SSTINDEX:
                        String sstIndex = value.toString();
                        try {
                            int idx = Integer.parseInt(sstIndex);
                            XSSFRichTextString rtss = new XSSFRichTextString(
                                    sharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(idx));
                            thisStr = '"' + rtss.toString() + '"';
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            output.println("Failed to parse SST index '" + sstIndex
                                    + "': " + ex.toString());
                        }
                        break;

                    case NUMBER:
                        String n = value.toString();
                        if (this.formatString != null)
                            thisStr = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double
                                    .parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex,
                                    this.formatString);
                        else
                            thisStr = n;
                        break;

                    default:
                        thisStr = "(TODO: Unexpected type: " + nextDataType + ")";
                        break;
                    }

                    // Output after we've seen the string contents
                    // Emit commas for any fields that were missing on this row
                    if (lastColumnNumber == -1) {
                        lastColumnNumber = 0;
                    }
                    for (int i = lastColumnNumber; i < thisColumn; ++i)
                        output.print(',');

                    // Might be the empty string.
                    output.print(thisColumn +" : "+thisStr);

                    // Update column
                    if (thisColumn > -1)
                        lastColumnNumber = thisColumn;

                } else if ("row".equals(name)) {

                    // Print out any missing commas if needed
                    if (minColumns > 0) {
                        // Columns are 0 based
                        if (lastColumnNumber == -1) {
                            lastColumnNumber = 0;
                        }
                        for (int i = lastColumnNumber; i < (this.minColumnCount); i++) {
                            output.print(',');
                        }
                    }



                    // We're onto a new row

                    output.println();
                    output.println(countrows++);
                    lastColumnNumber = -1;

                }

            }

            /**
             * Captures characters only if a suitable element is open. Originally
             * was just "v"; extended for inlineStr also.
             */
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {
                if (vIsOpen)
                    value.append(ch, start, length);
            }

            /**
             * Converts an Excel column name like "C" to a zero-based index.
             * 
             * @param name
             * @return Index corresponding to the specified name
             */
            private int nameToColumn(String name) {
                int column = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {
                    int c = name.charAt(i);
                    column = (column + 1) * 26 + c - 'A';
                }
                return column;
            }

        }

        // /////////////////////////////////////

        private OPCPackage xlsxPackage;
        private int minColumns;
        private PrintStream output;
        private Class clazz;

        /**
         * Creates a new XLSX -> CSV converter
         * 
         * @param pkg
         *            The XLSX package to process
         * @param output
         *            The PrintStream to output the CSV to
         * @param minColumns
         *            The minimum number of columns to output, or -1 for no minimum
         */
        public ExcelSheetParser(OPCPackage pkg, PrintStream output, int minColumns, Class clazz) {
            this.xlsxPackage = pkg;
            this.output = output;
            this.minColumns = minColumns;
            this.clazz = clazz;

        }

        /**
         * Parses and shows the content of one sheet using the specified styles and
         * shared-strings tables.
         * 
         * @param styles
         * @param strings
         * @param sheetInputStream
         */
        public void processSheet(StylesTable styles,
                ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, InputStream sheetInputStream)
                throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

            InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
            SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
            ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetHandler(styles, strings,
                    this.minColumns, this.output, this.clazz);
            sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
            sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
        }

        /**
         * Initiates the processing of the XLS workbook file to CSV.
         * 
         * @throws IOException
         * @throws OpenXML4JException
         * @throws ParserConfigurationException
         * @throws SAXException
         */
        public void process() throws IOException, OpenXML4JException,
                ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

            ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(
                    this.xlsxPackage);
            XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(this.xlsxPackage);

            StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
            XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader
                    .getSheetsData();
            int index = 0;
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                InputStream stream = iter.next();
                String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();
                this.output.println(sheetName + " [index=" + index + "]:");
                processSheet(styles, strings, stream);
                stream.close();
                ++index;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a SAX processor? XSSF classes already give you the data you need.  `XSSFWorkbook` implements `Iterable<XSSFSheet>`, `XSSFSheet` implements `Iterable<Row>`, and `XSSFRow` implements `Iterable<Cell>`.

Comment: @JimGarrison. Please see this. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

Comment: @anything Have you tried the library that I have mentioned in the example ?

Answer (score 1):

What I'd probably do is start building the User object when the row starts. As you hit the cells in the row, you populate your User object. When the row ends, validate the User object, and if it's fine add it then. Because you're doing SAX parsing, you'll get the start and events for all of these, so you can attach your logic there.

I'd suggest you take a look at [XLSX2CSV](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) in the Apache POI Examples. It shows how to go about handling the different kinds of cell contents (which you'll need for populating your user object), how to do something when you reach the end of the row, as well as handling missing cells etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a user object at following location in your code:

```
// We're onto a new row
output.println(); 
// Convert output to a new user object
// ....
// ....
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all where you are saving value in **thisStr** variable, if this is a valid value then put this value in Map.

You should create USer object in endElement() method in

```
else if ("row".equals(name)) {

  // use map create USER object here
}
```

and You can add Users object in global list and if you want to persist it then you can persist it sheet by sheet OR all data at a time.

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    InputStream stream = iter.next();
    String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();
    this.output.println(sheetName + " [index=" + index + "]:");
    processSheet(styles, strings, stream);
    stream.close();
    ++index;
   //for persisting  USERS data sheet by sheet write your code here.........
}
// for persisting complete data of all sheets write your code here...
```

This is working for me.