# apache poi - XSSF read formatted cell value

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

Is there any way I can get to the formatted value that excel shows in a row, versus the raw value I am getting returned from the stream?

Or would this fall under the "formula evaluation" category, which this does not support?

Comment: Are you trying to get the result of a formula cell?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the formatted value of a cell. As in, the raw value is 57.9826734, but the cell is formatted to round to two decimals, so when I actually open the spreadsheet I see  57.99. I actually need POI to spit out 57.99

Answer (score 16):

If you have the `Cell` that you're trying to get the data out of, try the following

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String formattedCellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(myCell);
```

If that doesn't get exactly what you're looking for, there are a number of different methods in the `DataFormatter` class that do the trick.  Check out the [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html).

Comment: Unfortunately with XSSF you lose all of the handy easy DOM classes like cell/row/etc. Check this link for a code example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372630/reading-an-excel-sheet-using-pois-xssf-and-sax-event-api -- and it looks like this code snippet might actually have what I need. Hallelujah! Thanks akokskis :)

Comment: ?? Your comment makes no sense to me...  Using XSSF, you have access to all of those classes in org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.  If you have an `XSSFWorkbook` (which extends `Workbook`), you can get an `XSSFSheet` (which extends `Sheet`), from which you can get an `XSSFRow` (which extends `Row`) from which you can get an `XSSFCell` (which extends `Cell`).  Once you have that `XSSFCell`, pass that along to the formatter and you'll get the value you're looking for.  No need to get into the SAX parsing.

Comment: if we have a formula, this gives the formula value. Is there a way to get the cached formula value, formatted?

Comment: `formatCellValue` accepts a second argument. You can get a FormulaEvaluator like this: `workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()`