# Apache POI: OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, memory, apache-poi, sax

I'm developing an app for the Kindle Fire that pulls a .xlsx file from dropbox and uses Apache POI to parse the data into an SQLite database (single table with 10 properties - I'll break it down into more tables once I can get the parsing working). The file is just over 2MB (~28,000 rows, 10 columns each), so when I initially started testing on a physical device (emulator worked fine, but was really slow), I ran into OutOfMemoryErrors. I did a lot of digging and found that I can implement SAX to reduce how much memory I'm using. However, I'm not really sure how to get all the data into my table - based on the example code I've looked at, each cell (at least from what I can tell) is evaluated individually, so I can't make one query per row iteration. The other issue I'm running into is I have a column of numbers (prices) that print to the console (through Debug.print()) twice, and I can't figure out why. I'm about at my wits end with this - I've spent several days fixing different issues with Dropbox and POI, but this one has me stumped. I'm using these three as templates/guides so far (mostly the latter):

http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html

https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/230453d76e6e912dfa22088544488a0a6baf83a2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.java

https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-apache-poi-library

And I've gone over these (among several others):

[How to read XLSX file of size >40MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345146/how-to-read-xlsx-file-of-size-40mb)

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/examples/FromHowTo.java

http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

[Reading an Excel sheet using POI's XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372630/reading-an-excel-sheet-using-pois-xssf-and-sax-event-api)

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java

It's a fairly simple application, so I don't need anything too fancy - just needs to run at this point. So I guess my questions are these: is SAX the best way for me to go to avoid memory issues? If so, how can I implement it to parse each row accurately into my database? If not, what direction should I move in? Here's what I have for my parsing class (runningTime and isParsing are being used for testing):

```
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;


public class ExcelParser {
    public static boolean isParsing = false;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private File dropboxFile;


    // purpose: parameterized constructor
    // parameters: FileInputStream inputStream
    // returns: nothing
    public ExcelParser(Context context, File dropboxFile) {
        this.dropboxFile = dropboxFile;
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }// end ExcelParser(FileInputStream inputStream)


    // purpose: parses the inputStream (.xlsx) into a list of Product objects
    // parameters: none
    // returns: void
    public void parseToDB() {
        Long runningTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        isParsing = true;
        Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "----- STARTING -----");

        try {
            OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(dropboxFile);
            XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
            SharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable = xssfReader.getSharedStringsTable();
            XMLReader parser = getSheetParser(sharedStringsTable);

            Iterator<InputStream> sheets = xssfReader.getSheetsData();
            Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "sheet processing");
            while(sheets.hasNext()) {
                Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Processing sheet");

                InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
                InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet);
                parser.parse(sheetSource);
                sheet.close();

                Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Done processing sheet");
            }// end while-loop
        } catch (SAXException | OpenXML4JException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            isParsing = false;
            Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "----- FINISHED : " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - runningTime) / 1000) + " seconds -----");
        }// end try-catch
    }// end parseToDB()


    //
    public XMLReader getSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable) throws SAXException {
        XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        ContentHandler handler = new SheetHandler(sharedStringsTable);
        parser.setContentHandler(handler);

        return parser;
    }// end getSheetParser(SharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable)


    // SHEET HANDLER CLASS
    private static class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private SharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable;
        private boolean fromSST, isCellValue, isNumber;
        private String contents;


        //
        private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable) {
            this.sharedStringsTable = sharedStringsTable;
        }// end SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sharedStringsTable)


        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // clear contents cache
            contents = "";

            // element row represents Row
            if(name.equals("row")) {
                String rowNumStr = attributes.getValue("r");
                Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Row# " + rowNumStr);
            }
            // element c represents Cell
            else if(name.equals("c")) {
                // attribute r represents the cell reference
                Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");

                // attribute t represents the cell type
                String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
                if (cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                    // cell type s means value will be extracted from SharedStringsTable
                    fromSST = true;
                } else if(cellType == null) {
                    // *likely a number
                    isNumber = true;
                }
            }
            // element v represents value of Cell
            else if(name.equals("v")) {
                isCellValue = true;
            }
        }// end startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes)


        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
            if(isCellValue)
                contents += new String(ch, start, length);
        }// end characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)


        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
            if(isCellValue) {
                if(fromSST) {
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(contents);
                    contents = new XSSFRichTextString(sharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(index)).toString();

                    Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Contents: " + contents + " >>");

                    isCellValue = false;
                    fromSST = false;
                } else if(isNumber) {
                    Debug.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Contents (num?): " + contents + " >>");
                }
            }
        }// end endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
    }// end class SheetHandler
}// end class ExcelParser
```

Comment: `XLSX2CSV.java` from the Apache POI examples is probably the best one to follow. Buffer up everything from a row, then dump to your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gagravarr's suggestion, I was able to work out a solution. I found an [updated implementation](https://github.com/oracle/cpq-cloud-with-paas-samples/blob/master/excel-to-csv/JCS-SX/src/main/java/oracle/cloud/sampleapps/Excel2Csv/XLSX2CSV.java) of the XLSX2CSV.java file (while searching for an efficient way to solve my problem) that printed each row of the .xlsx file into a CSVWriter. I adjusted the code in the endRow() method to insert a new row into my database instead of writing to the CSVWriter. It's still a little slow, but I'm not having memory issues anymore!